# Eclipse Mars CDT Makefile project C++14 support

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I'm using Mars (4.5.2). How do I get Eclipse CDT to treat my imported Makefile project as using C++14? Eclipse CDT can't even resolve unique_ptr in the source editor.

My Makefile is not a typical one. I'm just using it as a wrapper to invoke another build system (waf). The build itself succeeds and I'm thinking in principle at least, Eclipse CDT can tell exactly what gcc command-lines are used to compile by source files and hence figure out a lot of things like which C++ standard to use and where to find headers. But who knows what CDT expects of the Makefile? Maybe it gets confused because there are no gcc command-lines in it.